# Replacement in data frame result in R

Tags: r

I have a data.frame such as

```
       x= data.frame("w"=c(1,2,3,4,5),"z"=c(2,Inf,Inf,5, Inf))
```

and I want to calculate the following formula:

```
       exp(x$w) - exp(x$z)
       > exp(x$w) - exp(x$z)
      [1]  -4.670774       -Inf       -Inf -93.815009       -Inf
```

my goal is to replace exp(x$w) instead of all -Inf in results. how can I do this in an efficient way in R? It means I want the final result as follows:
(-4.670774,7.389056 , 20.085537, -93.815009,148.413159)

Comment: The value `e^INF` is, as expected, infinity.  It seems that you want the behavior of taking `e^-INF`, is that right?  If so, then your formula needs to be changed.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like below?

```
> do.call("-", Map(function(v) exp(replace(v, is.infinite(v), -Inf)), x))
[1]  -4.670774   7.389056  20.085537 -93.815009 148.413159
```

or

```
> do.call("-", replace(exp(x), is.infinite(as.matrix(x)), 0))
[1]  -4.670774   7.389056  20.085537 -93.815009 148.413159
```

or

```
> with(
+   x,
+   exp(w) - exp(ifelse(is.infinite(z), -Inf, z))
+ )
[1]  -4.670774   7.389056  20.085537 -93.815009 148.413159
```

or

```
> with(
+   x,
+   exp(w) - exp(z * (1 - 2 * is.infinite(z)))
+ )
[1]  -4.670774   7.389056  20.085537 -93.815009 148.413159
```

Comment: The `replace` idea could be rejigged to `ifelse` - `ifelse(is.infinite(x$z), exp(x$w), exp(x$w) - exp(x$z))`

Comment: @thelatemail Yes, thanks! Added `ifelse` approach, and we can also do without `ifelsef` or `replace`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you can try `case_when()` function from `library(dplyr)` to state the conditions for `z`:

```
library(dplyr)

x %>%
  dplyr::mutate(z, z= case_when(z == Inf~ exp(w),
                         z != Inf ~ exp(z)))
```

Console output:

```
#  w          z
#1 1   7.389056
#2 2   7.389056
#3 3  20.085537
#4 4 148.413159
#5 5 148.413159
```